# bash get value from long string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

i dont understand sed, awk or grep - i try the last 3 hours to get a result, but i dont get the right answer.

What i have: 
i get this information from icloud.com

```
{u'timeStamp': 1470252602355, u'locationFinished': True, u'longitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX, u'positionType': u'GPS-Course', u'locationType': None, u'latitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX, u'isOld': False, u'isInaccurate': False, u'horizontalAccuracy': 200.0}
```

this is the location of my iphone.

but i only need the latitude and the longitude. i have try with AWK, sed and grep - i dont become the right result.

Comment: In general, you can't rely on any of these tools to parse JSON, since they are all line-oriented, and you can't predict where line breaks might occur in JSON. Use tools designed for JSON (like `jsawk` and `jq` mentioned in the answers), or use a language (e.g. Python) that has a library for parsing JSON.

Comment: Although, how exactly are you getting this result? That looks more like the string representation of a Python `dict`, possibly the result of parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go...

```
 $ tr ',' '\n' <file | grep '\(lati\|longi\)tude'
 u'longitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX
 u'latitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

or, without `tr`

```
$ grep -o '\(lati\|longi\)tude[^,]*' file
longitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX
latitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

In sed (where a.json is your file), it will print just the longitude value and the latitude value):

```
sed "s/.*u'longitude': \([^,]\+\).*u'latitude': \([^,]\+\).*/\1 \2/g" a.json
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i need. i swear, i will more read about expressions...

Answer (score 1):

Looking like a json. You can parse it using [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk), I haven't used it but looks like it will solve your problem easily.

```
echo "your json string" | jsawk "this.latitude"
```

Note: this will give answer(thanks sjsam). Handling regex can became more complex if json string varies. So better to handle this string as json not as ordinary string.

Answer (score 1):

This grep pipe will snag those fields:

`grep -o "'l[^:]\+itude':[^,]\+"`

Answer (score 0):

Like `jsawk`, you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to process your JSON:

```
json="{u'timeStamp': 1470252602355, u'locationFinished': True, u'longitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX, u'positionType': u'GPS-Course', u'locationType': None, u'latitude': XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX, u'isOld': False, u'isInaccurate': False, u'horizontalAccuracy': 200.0}"
echo "$json" | jq '.latitude'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS=',' -F'[\n:][[:space:]]*' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i ~ /(lat|long)itude/) print $(i+1) }' file
XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX
XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```